# lost events delegation after remove(), apendTo() and apend()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

Do you know any issue about remove, appendTo and append methods, because I lost event delegation when I remove and append another place.

Comment: have you tried using .detach() instead of .remove()?

Comment: i tried detach also.. after it all events invisible..

Comment: I can see it working, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using .detach() will keep events on the object.

Here is what I tested and worked: http://jsfiddle.net/9eZtM/4/

Answer (score 0):

No I really don't.

you could try `.detach()` instead of `.remove()`

Comment: thank you too genesis! but valipour give really life jacket answer.